# Change Magento My Order 2.4.4 Date Format

Tags: magento2.4, date

I'm trying to change the date format from **3/6/22** to **03/06/2022** in this file:

`/app/code/Magento/Sales/view/frontend/templates/order/history.phtml`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cnCT.jpg

How can I edit the following code?

`<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAt()) ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As quick solution you can create helper in your module

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;

class Date extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var TimezoneInterface
     */
    protected $timezone;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $locale;

    public function __construct(Context $context, TimezoneInterface $timezone, ResolverInterface $localeResolver)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->timezone = $timezone;
        $this->locale = $localeResolver->getLocale();
    }

    public function formatDate(string $value, string $format): string
    {
        $convertedDate = $this->timezone->date(
            new \DateTime($value, new \DateTimeZone('UTC')),
            $this->locale,
            true
        );

        return $convertedDate->format($format);
    }
}
```

and use this helper in template

```
// define it in the top
$_dateHelper = $this->helper(\Acme\StackExchange\Helper\Date::class);

// use
echo $_dateHelper->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAt(), 'm/d/Y');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! i have following error with your code: ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO). Why? Thanks

Comment: Inside HTML use `<?= $_dateHelper->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAt(), 'm/d/Y'); ?>`. `<?=` equal `<?php echo `

Comment: Okay thanks now error is different.. Error: Class 'MakeDo\DateTime\Helper\Date' not found in /home/web/aarte.com.au/www/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121

Comment: Make sure you properly registered your module `MakeDo\DateTime` and make sure you've specified correct namespace and class name for helper

Comment: I made a quick video if you have time for check it :) https://we.tl/t-0N0udUag2q

Comment: In your video file called *Data*, but should call *Date*